# Simple Redux-React trying to updating state by this.props.dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

When I click on checkbox, `this.props.dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"});`causes this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

I would be so grateful for some help, also just so you know this project is running in Typescript with React and Redux.

As a Redux Newby, I am just trying to simply change the HTML checkbox checked property from true to false or visa versa, when checkbox is clicked. My presentation component has the onclick logic that is successfully calling a handleCheckedChange function with expected data being passed in. This is tested and working.

However when I run: `this.props.dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"});` from my `handleCheckedChange()`:

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
./src/containers/App.tsx.App.handleCheckedChange [as onChange]
src/containers/App.tsx:64
```

> 64 |     this.props.dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"});

I have tried putting in the mapDispatchToProps function and then adding it to the connect statement, but then props no longer shows the dispatch() in the Chrome React Developer Inspect.

I also successfully ran `store.dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"});` from the index.tsx where the reducer lives.

Also I feel pretty confident in my redux code in index.tsx, because I have already successfully setup a store, connect and mapStateToProps to read the fields in from the redux store.

reducer from  Index.tsx:

```
  function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

     switch ( action.type ) {
        case "unCommunicationChecked":
          return {
            CommunicationChecked: false
          };
        case "unIdMyDeviceChecked":
          return {
            IdMyDeviceChecked: false
          };
        case "unPreferredChecked":
          return {
            PreferredChecked: false
          };
        case "addCommunicationChecked":
          return {
            CommunicationChecked: true
          };
        case "addIdMyDeviceChecked":
          return {
            IdMyDeviceChecked: true
          };
        case "addPreferredChecked":
          return {
            PreferredChecked: true
          };  
        default:
          return state;
      }
  }

const store = createStore(reducer);

// store.dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"}); successful results



  App.tsx:
    class App extends React.Component <Props, State> {

      handleCheckedChange(newCheck: boolean, Checktype: string) {

        if (newCheck === true) {
            Checktype = "un" + Checktype;
        } else if (newCheck === false) {
            Checktype = "add" + Checktype;
        } else {
            console.log("Bad handleCheckedChange call");
        }        
        this.props.dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"});

      }
```

Comment: Have you binded handleCheckedChange inside your constructor? The this keyword would not be pointing to the right place if you have not.

Comment: I am not currently using a constructor, because I am using a redux store for state and passing props data in between container component to presentation component, like so

Comment: <EmailCopy 
                        email={this.props.email}
                        CommunicationChecked={this.props.CommunicationChecked}
                        IdMyDeviceChecked={this.props.IdMyDeviceChecked}
                        PreferredChecked={this.props.PreferredChecked}
                        onAdd={this.handleAdd}
                        onChange={this.handleCheckedChange}
                    />

Comment: I am passing props into my export const EmailCopy = (props) => {  return ( .....  My html looks like <input type="checkbox" checked={props.PreferredChecked} onClick={props.onChange.bind(props, props.PreferredChecked)}/> Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following minimum requirements for [Redux](https://redux.js.org) to work:

1. [Reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers). You have one `function reducer(state = initialState, action)`. But it should be corrected. See below.
2. [Connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) your component to store

   ```
   export default connect(
       (state) => state, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
       (dispatch) => {
           return { 
               addPreferredChecked: () => dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"}),
               addIdMyDeviceChecked: () => dispatch ({type: "addIdMyDeviceChecked"})
           }
       })(App);
   ```

`addPreferredChecked` and `addIdMyDeviceChecked` are called [action creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators).

3. You should use Provider to provide access to store for `App` component

   ```
   ReactDOM.render(
       <Provider store={store}>
           <App />
       </Provider>,
       document.getElementById('root')
   )
   ```

Also your `reducer` is incorrect. Reducer should always [return new state](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions), but your reducer returns only chaned part of state.

Correct reducer can look like

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case "unCommunicationChecked":
            return {
                ...state,
                CommunicationChecked: false
            };
       // And so on. Add ...state to all cases
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7k8vo39r3q)

Comment: I added:  export default connect(mapStateToProps, (dispatch) => {
    addPreferredChecked: () => dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"})
}) (App);   & referenced it with:   this.props.dispatch({addPreferredChecked});   The addPreferredChecked is being accessed as a label and it cannot be found by this.props.dispatch. I tried injecting it to the props by returning the code, but then I am getting the same error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Is my syntax incorrect? I am assuming that this is the action: dispatch({type: "addPreferredChecked"}) and I do not need an action.js file, right? Thank you to the moon and back for helping.

Comment: I have added working example to answer.(https://codesandbox.io/s/7k8vo39r3q) and several clarifications

Comment: Your working example is brilliant and it was so so helpful, thank you very much! I finally got the dispatch working and I was able to inject the addPreferredChecked to my props. I have now one piece left to go. I am using a container component(App) that calls a presentation component (EmailCopy). The App has the connect and redux awareness, while Email copy has the checkbox HTML with the onclick event.

Comment: I have been binding my props between container and presentation components by

Comment: <EmailCopy 
                        email={this.props.email}
                        CommunicationChecked={this.props.CommunicationChecked}
                        IdMyDeviceChecked={this.props.IdMyDeviceChecked}
                        PreferredChecked={this.props.PreferredChecked}
                        onclick={this.props.addPreferredChecked}
                    />

Comment: And what is the problem with props binding?

Comment: Html: <div className="ui checkbox padding"> <input type="checkbox" checked={props.PreferredChecked} onClick={props.addPreferredChecked}/> Can you see any reason why it is not finding the injected addPreferredChecked in Props or do I even need to do this?

Comment: The Checkbox's onClick={props.addPreferredChecked} is ultimately not getting to my reducer.

Comment: May be you should use `onClick={this.props.addPreferredChecked}`? I've modified example and added `ReduxButton` component to it to showcase

Comment: I fixed it, I changed: onclick={this.props.addPreferredChecked} to addPreferredChecked={this.props.addPreferredChecked}. Now its toggling the check mark on and off. I am going to make the changes for the other three checkboxes and I am very hopeful I can get it all working easily now. Its awesome, how using !state.PreferredChecked makes the toggle function work, its brilliant. Thank you so so so very much!  I will check back when I am done, to let you know its all working and then mark the checkmark above to say its a working solution.

Comment: @Fydor All good, thanks so much for everything, this is resolved.